# Which sentence is grammatically or syntactically correct?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, prepositional-phrases, syntax

1. a. He is the specialist in chemistry at the podium.
   b. He is the specialist at the podium in chemistry.
2. a. He is a contender with a shoulder injury for the Best Chef title.
   b. He is a contender for the best chef title with a shoulder injury.
3. a. Which part of a title is he a contender for?
   b. Which part of his body is he a contender with?

Although 2. and 3. are both awkward sentences, what are the correct sentences grammatically or syntactically?

I am attending a syntax class. My professor gave me this question.
I am considering this question for two days. Please, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put the prepositional phrase that modifies the noun ***immediately after*** the noun.

I think you didn't copy these sentences perfectly, because they all seem to have grammar issues. (In the future, if you want a faster response, please take care to make sure the sentences are copied correctly.) I've fixed these issues in the examples below:

> That's the ***specialist in chemistry*** at the podium. **[CORRECT]**
>
> That's the ***specialist*** at the podium ***in chemistry.*** **[INCORRECT]**

***In chemistry*** describes ***specialist***.

> He is a ***contender*** with a shoulder injury ***for the Best Chef title***. **[INCORRECT]**
>
> He is a ***contender for the Best Chef title*** with a shoulder injury.
>   **[CORRECT]**

***For the Best Chef title*** describes ***contender***.

Question 3a and 3b hardly make any sense. They just seem to be follow-up questions to question 2. I've tried to fix them up:

> Which title is he a contender for? **[CORRECT]**
>
> Which part of his body is he contending with? **[INCORRECT]**

Technically, you *can* contend with a shoulder injury. But it's obvious here that the contender is contending for a title.

Note, you shouldn't end a sentence with prepositions. These sentences have numerous errors and make it very hard to comprehend.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it!! Yes, actually I changed sentences. I'm sorry for confusing you. I can't thank you enough.